# Set of discrete orbits under subgroup of $Isom(\mathbb{E}^n)$ is clopen

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry, topological-groups, isometry

I'm trying to solve the following exercise (exercise 1.4 from Szczepanski's "Geometry of Crystallographic Groups"):

> Let $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of $I(\mathbb{E}^n)$, the group of isometries on $\mathbb{E}^n$. Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\forall x \in \mathbb{E}^n$, the orbit $\Gamma \cdot x$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{E}^n$
> 2. $\exists x \in \mathbb{E}^n$, the orbit $\Gamma \cdot x$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{E}^n$

Of course, 1. implies 2. I'm having trouble with the reverse implication, however. I'd like to show that the set $\{x \in \mathbb{E}^n \mid \Gamma \cdot x \text{ is discrete}\}$ is an open and closed set. Then this set must be either $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{E}^n$, and the existence of an $x$ with discrete orbit proves the exercise.

One tool that I have is the projection
$$\pi: \mathbb{E^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{E}^n/\Gamma: x \mapsto \Gamma \cdot x,$$
which is continuous, open and closed. I'm not sure if this helps in any way, though.

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is false for all $n\ge 2$. Think of $\Gamma=O(n)$. For which choice of $x$ the orbit $\Gamma x$ is a discrete subset of $R^n$?

Comment: @studiosus Ah, you're right of course. $O(n) \cdot 0 = {0}$ which is discrete, but for any $x \neq 0$ the orbit is the sphere of radius $\|x\|$, which is clearly not discrete. I should've been more critical of the question itself, I guess. 

If you post this as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll just delete the question I guess. Also going to update the question to reference the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is false for all $n\ge 2$. Consider $\Gamma=O(n)$. For $x=0$ the orbit $\Gamma x$ is a discrete subset of $R^n$, but for any $x\ne 0$ the orbit is not discrete.